# .NET Core ArugmentNullException causing hard crash in WebAPI app? why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So I just ran across this very odd issue building a simple WebAPI template using .NET Core (2.1.200 cli) and VSCode (1.23.1). Most exceptions, if thrown, put me into the VSCode debugger and upon continuing return a Developer Exception page sent to the browser. However when a ArugmentNullException is thrown... hard crashes the application with no VSCode debugger interaction.

**Program.cs** (default webapi template code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ExceptionIssue {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs** (default webapi template code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ExceptionIssue {
  public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseMvc();
    }
  }
}
```

**.\Controllers\ValuesController.cs** (modified get)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ExceptionIssue.Controllers {
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class ValuesController : Controller {
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id) {
      String result = null;
      switch (id) {
        case 1:
          throw new Exception("One");
        break;
        case 2:
          throw new ArgumentNullException("Two");
        break;
        case 3:
          result = String.Format(null, "UH OH");
        break;        
        case 4:
          String template = null;
          result = String.Format(template, "UH OH");
        break;
      }
      return result;
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value) {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value) {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id) {
    }
  }
}
```

- Also note that *String.Format(null, "UH OH");* returns "UH OH" whereas *String.Format(template, "UH OH);* throws a ArgumentNullException (not sure why there is a difference, shouldn't they both do the same thing).

Not sure if this is a .NET Core, Kestrel, or VSCode issue, but it's 100% reproducible on my part.

Comment: "not sure why there is a difference, shouldn't they both do the same thing" - no, the first is calling `string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, object[])` and using null to mean "the current culture", so it's fine for that to return "UH OH".

Comment: Do you have any Exception Handling code in there? It is actually pretty easy to screw up with too agressive catching. And if that catch block then does a "Application.Close()" or similar code (not sure about the proper WPF variant), it would easily account for that behavior.

Comment: Actually this question is about the hard crash on ArgumentNullException, the String.Format was just a side-note.

Comment: My bad, I interpreted the question wrong.

Comment: @DaisyShipton thanks for the insight on the String.Format side-note. I should have looked at what constructor was actually being called, that makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Are there a list of Exceptions that the debugger will or won't ignore in VSC?  In VS Pro it's possible to break on everything or to ignore certain Exception Types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple co-developers helping me dig deep on this, and it looks like this is actually an issue with the ms-vscode.chsarp (1.15.1) debugger itself.

Running my code without debugging (CTRL-F5) works as expected. Likewise running my code with debugging on an older version of the debugger also works as expected. So this appears to be bug in the latest version of the debugger, which makes sense since the app just hard crashes without even breaking on the line that threw the exception.

Guess I'll bring this to the guys over at Omnisharp.

Comment: Issue had been added to their GitHub: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2297